# Two-Sided confidence interval

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

If I have a random sample $X_1^2, X_2^2, ... ,X_{100}^2$ with $X_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, how can I find the two sided confidence interval for $\sigma^2$ based on my sample, using an $\alpha = 0.05$

Comment: Consider $S_n=X_1^2+X_2^2+\cdots+X_n^2$, then CLT yields $S_n=n\sigma^2+\tau\sqrt{n}Z_n$ where $\tau^2=2\sigma^4$ denotes the variance of each $X_k^2$ and $Z_n$ converges in distribution to a standard random variable $Z$ wen $n\to\infty$. Thus, $$P(n\sigma^2+\tau\sqrt{n}a<S_n<n\sigma^2+\tau\sqrt{n}b)\to P(a<Z<b)=\Phi(b)-\Phi(a).$$ Choose your favorite interval $(a,b)$ such that $\Phi(b)-\Phi(a)=1-\alpha$ and deduce the interval $$\frac{S_n}{n+b\sqrt{2n}}<\sigma^2<\frac{S_n}{n+a\sqrt{2n}}.$$

Comment: was there anything wrong with my approach in the comments to @user2566092 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.kean.edu/~fosborne/bstat/06evar.html where it is described how the distribution of the variance estimator is related to a chi-squared distribution and they tell you the number of degrees of freedom for the chi-squared. (It's crucial to assume your original distribution is normal). To get confidence intervals for such a chi-squared distribution, you can e.g. see Wikipedia page on chi-squared distribution and get the CDF.

Comment: Okay, so. Will I need to first construct a likelihood function for the $\chi ^2$ distribution, and then use the MLE to find $\sigma^2$ ?

Comment: @elbarto Or you can just use the plug-in estimator for the variance to get the center of your confidence interval, and then use the chi-squared relationship just to get the confidence interval. This will be very close to correct.

Comment: Okay, @user25622092, I will have to concede that I am very behind on my work and barely know the content confidently. So at the risk of making a fool out of myself, I don't really know what you mean "plug-in estimator for the variance", unless you are referring to the sample variance?

In any case, do I suppose $S^2$ is the sample variance, and for a sample of size  $100$ from $N(0,\sigma^2)$, we have $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ is $\chi^2(100-1)$?

Then, $P[ \chi^2 _{1- \alpha /2}(99) \leq \frac{(99)S^2}{\sigma^2} \leq \chi^2 _{\alpha/2}(99)] = 1-\alpha$

Comment: Anyway to elaborate;

we let $\alpha = 0.05$, $99S^2  = \sum_{i=1}^{100} (x_i-0)^2 = 99\sigma^2$ ?
Which leaves us with:
$P[ \frac{99 \sigma^2}{\chi_{0.975}^2(99)} \leq \sigma^2 \leq \frac{99 \sigma^2}{\chi_{0.025}^2(99)}]=.095$

I found a table on wikipedia which when up to 10 degrees of freedom for $\chi^2$.. so this just seems, wrong? should it be the square root of $99$ ?

How do I deal with the fact that I have $\sigma^2$ on both sides of that inequality?